# How to use scanf to read single digits from a consecutive stream of digits

Tags: c

I got input like `12345679890` but I just want to read 1 digit at a time: that is, read `1` then `2` then `3`... and do some operations next. However, when I use `scanf`, it reads all the digits ie: `1234567890`. Can anyone help?

This is the code that I have

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int input;
    scanf("%x", &input);
    
    while (scanf("%x", &input) == 1) {
    }
}
```

Comment: `%1d` instead of `%x`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thank you!! I got one more question, do you know why when I try to print all the input in the while loop, it cannot print first input?

Comment: you're overwriting the value from the 1st scanf, from before the while loop even starts

Comment: `scanf("%x",&input);` is first one. delete this line.

Comment: got it, thank you all !!

Answer (score 1):

`12345679890` *is* an integer, what you want to do is read one *digit* at a time. To do this, you would use the format string `%1u` rather than `%x`.

For a start, `%x` specifies a *hexadecimal* item, meaning it will accept `a` through `f` as well, and `%d` would allow for a leading sign which you probably don't want.

In addition, you appear to consume (and throw away) the first digit *before* you enter the loop, so you would be better off with something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned int digit;
    while (scanf("%1d", &digit) == 1) {
        //doSomethingWith(digit);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that the POSIX specification for [`scanf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) says: _`u` —
Matches an optionally signed decimal integer._. The C standard says the same in [§7.21.6.2 The `scanf` function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2).  You'd need to use `%[0-9]` and a character pointer to be sure of getting one digit without any sign, and then you'd need to subtract `'0'` from the result to get a number 0..9 instead of 48..57 (with an ASCII-based code set; strictly, that range would be `'0'..'9'`).